# How to correct the Flaw in this function

Tags: php

How to correct the Flaw in this function

```
 class MyClass {
  private $_callingscript; 
             public   function __construct(){
    $this->_callingscript= basename($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']);
        }
        public static function Setvalue($k,$v){
   if (!empty($k)) {
   $_SESSION[$this->_callingscript.'_'.$k]= $v;//This doesnot work 
   $_SESSION[$_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'].'_'.$k]=$v //This works 

  }
        }
 }

 MyClass::setValue('Somename',"Somevalue");
```

When i call this it is giving me error  "Using `$this` when not in object context in".
 How to correct the callingscript variable .Is this due to private declaration  of that variable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to refactor your code so that you either:

- make `Setvalue` a non-static function and instantiate the class:

  ```
  $mc = new MyClass();
  $mc->setValue('Somename', 'Somevalue'");
  ```

or

- change `_callingscript` so that it is not populated through instantiation and can therefore be accessed statically via `self::_callingscript`

Answer (score 6):

No, it's because `$this` doesn't get populated for static methods. Remove the `static` qualifier.

Answer (score 0):

`$this` can't be accessed from within static methods. <strike>I would recommend replacing the line that dosent work to:</strike>

```
$_SESSION[self::_callingscript. "_" .$k] = $v;
```

EDIT: come to think about it, this will not work.

---

Attempt #2: I gave you bad information. I did forget that calling the static method would not call the __construct() method. What I do is just use non static methods...

```
class MyClass {

  private $_callingscript; 

  public function __construct()
  {
    $this->_callingscript = basename($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']);
  }


  public function setValue($k, $v)
  {
    if (!empty($k)) {
      $_SESSION[$this->_callingscript. "_" .$k] = $v;
    }
  }

}


$MyClass = new MyClass();

$MyClass->setValue('Somename', "Somevalue");
```

Sorry for confusion.

Comment: I don't think this will work either. You are calling the static setValue directly, so no construct is called and so the $_callingscript variable is not set at that point. If it doesnt crash you would have a "null" value in best case. @Someone I recommend webbidaves solution, refactor the class, thats the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

You could use:

```
class MyClass { 
    public static function Setvalue($k, $v) { 
        static $callingScript = null;

        if($callingScript == null) {
            $callingScript = basename($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']);
        }

        if (!empty($k)) {
            $_SESSION[$callingScript . '_'.$k]= $v;
        }
    }
}
```

or if the callingScript variable needs to be shared among other methods:

```
class MyClass {
    private static $callingScript = null;

    private static function getCallingScript() {
        if(self::$callingScript == null) {
            self::$callingScript = basename($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']);
        }

        return self::$callingScript;
    }

    public static function Setvalue($k, $v) { 
        if (!empty($k)) {
            $_SESSION[self::getCallingScript() . '_'.$k]= $v;
        }
    }
}
```

As others have pointed out, `$this` is not accessible within static methods and if you call a `static` method the `__construct` function is not being triggered.